# no push notification after change is detected in realtime database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying to create a push notification and after a comment is made in my realtime database.

I use this code which I learned from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=en)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions' 
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

 export const sendenPushNeu = functions.database

 .ref ('/placeID/{placeID}')
 .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

   
   var app = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert('/Users/...Desktop/firebasedesktop/key.json')
    });

var registrationToken = 'dplk1...bS7eu';
var message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  token: registrationToken
};

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
 })
```

But I don't get a notification.

I am new to javascript and cannot see what is wrong here.

Comment: It looks like you're not [importing the Admin SDK](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+functions+firebase+importing+the+%22admin%22+sdk). One example of how to do that: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/install-admin-sdk

Comment: I did the tutorial and got the key.json but it still won't work. it says TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cert')
    at file:///workspace/index.js:11:36
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:78:23)"

Comment: Nope still the same error. This javascript thing is really hard to understand and there are not a lot of tutorials for that.